# Github Actions Substitute String before Deploying

Tags: github, yaml, version, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am trying to develop a Github Action to update the Version Number and DB credentials in my (mostly) php files before uploading to a FTP server.

Inside my main branch, I have a textfile called `VERSION.md` with the content `2.0.1`.

The action should run on each push commit.

Before deploying to a FTP server, these substitutions are required (of course, the *real* repository files should not be changed, only the files which are uploaded to the server).

- For each file, the string `__VERSION__` should be replaced with the content of my `VERSION.md` file.
- In addition, only for the file `db_connection.php`, the string `__DB-PASSWORD__` should be replaced with the corresponding secret `DB_PASSWORD`.

This is my current workflow:

```
on: push
name: FTP Deploy
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: Ubuntu VM
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Getting latest Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2
    
    # at this position I tried the string replacing

    - name: Sync Files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: "public_html/"
        exclude: .git*
          - .git*/**
          - fonts/ttf/**
          - symbols/**
          - README.md
          - VERSION.md
```

As a first test, I have tried

```
- name: Set Tokens
      run: perl -pi -e 's/getString\(R\.string\.token\)/"$ENV{TOKEN}"/' 'index.php'
      env:
        TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

to replace only for `index.php` the string `TOKEN` with a token stored in my secrets, but this fails. Everything looks ok, but there is no change a the server.

Comment: What does your workflow look like, and how does it fail?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @BenjaminW. I have improved my question above hoping for help or a hint :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sed` to do this

For example to replace 'foo' with 'bar' - `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' input_file`

```yaml
- name: Replace credentials
  run: |
    find . -name "*" -exec sed -i "s/__VERSION__/$(cat VERSION.md)/g" {} +
    sed -i 's/__DB-PASSWORD__/${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}/g' db_connection.php
```